# How to handle user_row_actions in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

First of all, I have not find solution for my problem. I have read few articles and thread to create a user actions , and tried the following code.

```
function kv_admin_deactivate_link($actions, $user_object) {

    $actions['deactivate_user'] = "<a href='" . admin_url( "users.php?action=deactivate&amp;user=$user_object->ID") . "'>" . __( 'Deactivate', 'kvc' ) . "</a>";

    return $actions;
}

add_filter('user_row_actions', 'kv_admin_deactivate_link', 10, 2);
```

After using the above code it gets me the additional action with users list as like in the below screenshot.

[image]

Now, my problem is, I don't know how to proceed to write my codes to deactivate a user. So can you help me to write function to handle `/wp-admin/users.php?action=deactivate&user=41`. Here I am writing these function for my wordpress theme and how can I write function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you to perform your deactivate operation  function.  just create a admin menu with the following code.

```
function xxxadmin_submenu_email() {         
        add_menu_page('Your menu', 'Your menu', 'manage_options', 'deactivate' , 'xxx_deactivate_functions', '', 66);
    }
add_action('admin_menu', 'xxxadmin_submenu_email');
```

Now, it will get you a page  and you have to write function inside `xxx_deactivate_functions` it. Here is sample code.

```
function xxx_deactivate_functions() {
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']== 'deactivate'){
        $user_id = $_GET['user'];
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    }

}
```

And I have modified your function like the below one.

```
function kv_admin_deactivate_link($actions, $user_object) {
    $actions['deactivate_user'] = "<a href='" . admin_url( "users.php?page=deactivate&amp;action=deactivate&amp;user=$user_object->ID") . "'>" . __( 'Deactivate', 'kvc' ) . "</a>";
    return $actions;
}
add_filter('user_row_actions', 'kv_admin_deactivate_link', 10, 2);
```

This is one way to do this.  But wait for some other experts solution to  code it better way.  Hope its helpful for urgent need.

Comment: let me try this, Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Yes, you solved my issue. its working. i don't think to wait for possible other solution now.